# backbone set module going into infilinte loop - backbon

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am not getting why my  page is going on infinite loop.

```
contentApi: {
        url: 'testurl',
        type: 'GET',
        done (response, module) {
           var data = {content: {}};
            response.elements.forEach(el => {
                if(el.id == 'claims_center_btn_download_all')
                    el.url = module.claimsApi.proxy.baseurl + 'download/forms/package';
                 data.content[el.id] = el;

            })
            module.data.set('content', response);
        }
    }
```

Any help will be really appreciable

Comment: Is there any listeners on the model ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a syntax issue, `done` looks like it should be declared as a property:

```
contentApi: {
    url: 'testurl',
    type: 'GET',
    done: function (response, module) {
       var data = {content: {}};
        response.elements.forEach(el => {
            if(el.id == 'claims_center_btn_download_all')
                el.url = module.claimsApi.proxy.baseurl + 'download/forms/package';
             data.content[el.id] = el;

        })
        module.data.set('content', response);
    }
}
```